# Unable to access id of directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a 'visibility' directive defined as following:

```
<span id="visibilityFor{{post.metaData.assetId}}" visibility></span>
```

and the corresponding directive code in JS is

```
myAppModule.directive("visibility", function ($compile, $http) {
return {
    scope: {
        id:"="
    },
    link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind('mouseover', function () {
            alert("hi");

        });
    }
    }
});
```

I am trying to access the 'id' of span in the model. But I get it as undefined. What could be the reason behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `=` you want to get a reference to an object defined in parent scope, but your `id` is probably just a string. If you want to treat the value as string use `@` instead of `=`. Like here:

```
scope: {
    id:"@"
},
link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
    element.bind('mouseover', function () {
        alert("hi");

    });
}
```

You can also retrieve value of `id` from `attrs` parameter by: `attrs.id` -- it will always be treated as string in this scenario and probably it is a better approach.

Comment: When I change "=" to "@", the whole directive stops working. It no longer prints "hi" alert.

Comment: did you try the other approach? did it generate some errors? do you have more code in your directive?

Comment: @Adarsh both options work perfectly fine for me. are you sure you create unique `id`s?

Comment: Hi.. Yes the problem was with the id. Thanks a ton.